# How to prevent automatic calendar in CSV?

Tags: excel, csv, datetime, calendar

I am working on files with deidentified, shifted dates/years. (For instance, the dates are like 2/6/2588, or 10/21/3105, which are non-existing in real world) While those bunch of dates/years look random, actually they're chronologically correlated, and I don't want anyone to touch.

Then Excel was kind enough to manage the dates for me, changing everything into somewhere between year 1900-2010, of course without my permission.

What's the best way to make excel not touching this, so that I can save my csv?

Comment: Try selecting the entire column, and under `format` menu set the type to `text`. This would work only once. When you(or someone) opens it again, then you have repeat this step again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use text to columns you can select the type of data in step 3. So select the column with your data, select text to columns, and in the last step click on the header for the column with the fake dates (click in the example for the data). You can then select the data type and if you do not want excel to touch the dates you can select text.

Answer (score 1):

Is the data coming from text files?  Or do you type it directly into Excel.  If typing, try `="2/6/2588"` or `'2/6/2588` to force Excel to interpret as string